# Show that $\dfrac{\pi}{\sin \pi z} = \dfrac{1}{z} + \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} (-1)^n \left(\dfrac{1}{z-n} + \dfrac{1}{z+n}\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

Show that:

$$
\dfrac{\pi}{\sin \pi z} = \dfrac{1}{z} + \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} (-1)^n \left(\dfrac{1}{z-n} + \dfrac{1}{z+n}\right)
$$

where $z\in \mathbb C \backslash \mathbb Z$

---

Let's note $\phi(z) = \dfrac{1}{z} + \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} (-1)^n \left(\dfrac{1}{z-n} + \dfrac{1}{z+n}\right)$.

I can "feel" it: both meromorphic functions have the same poles and have the same equivalent near each of them (I mean $\dfrac{\pi}{\sin \pi z} \underset{z \to p}{\sim} \dfrac{1}{(-1)^p(z-p)}$).

But what to conclude with the difference $\dfrac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)} - \phi(z)$?

Comment: entire, periodic with period $1$ and bounded at imaginary infinity on a period strip, hence bounded there, bounded in the plane etc

Comment: @Conrad Why would that function be expendable as an entire one?

Comment: pretty much by definition $\dfrac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)} - \phi(z)$ has no poles in the plane, while $\phi$ is given by a compactly convergent series outside the integers so it is meromorphic like $\dfrac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$ and a meromorphic function without poles is entire

Comment: @Conrad OK yeah that was pretty straightforward...Thank you!

Comment: happy to be of help